# Is it possible to perform e2e test with Karma and angular with a real httpBackend?

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

I am in the  development phase of a small web project and I would like to write some end to end tests that exercise my rest services, and ensure they behave as expected.  I think this project would get more out of testing the full flow than it would testing individual components.

I am using karma for the remainder of my angular client tests, and would like to keep to one test runner.

I know this isn't going to work, without some other magic:

```
describe('e2e: http factory  test Definition', function(){
    'use strict';

    var myHttp = null ;

    beforeEach(module('myNgApplication'));
    beforeEach(inject(function (MyHttp) {
        myHttp = MyHttp
    }))

    it('has a functioning MyHttp factory object', (function (done) {

        //test the get
        var getPromise = myHttp.
            path('/').
            path('rest').
            path('v1').
            path('is-alive').
            get()


        getPromise.then(function(data){
            expect(data).to.be.a('string')

            var getDataObject = JSON.parse(data)

            done()
        }) ;


    }));

}); //completed test case for case-summary
```

Comment: why don't you try protractor?

Comment: I am trying to keep the set of tools I ma learning limited to a few to master at any given time.  Is there no way to do  it with Karma?

Comment: I mean you can try to test the data that returns from the your API call, I'd say to me that's the equivalent of a full "integration" test but not as a proper "e2e", in real life I found more practical to use protractor since that is a very high quality test near to user experience